# Make a div image clickable when doing position: absolute

Tags: html, css

I need to put up a site skin on my site where there is one 336x768px image on the left on the main content area and another image on the right of the main content area.

I am able to position it correctly, but I'm not able to make the image clickable. I believe it's related to the z-index of the containers, but I'm not having any luck adjusting them.

I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate and show my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/puTEe/

By clicking on the images on the left and right, you should be clicking a link to google/yahoo.

The CSS:

```
.site-skin {
    width: 96px;
    height: 76px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#skin-right {
    right: 0;
}

#main-container {
    width: 96px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="site-skin">
      <a href="http://google.com">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/96x76">
      </a>
  </div>

  <div class="site-skin" id="skin-right">
      <a href="http://yahoo.com">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/96x76">
      </a>
  </div>

  <div id="main-container">
      main content
  </div>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using a negative z-index? That's your problem. Make them non-negative and they work fine.

Just a note, negative z-index values are permitted, however since your `#main-container` has no z-index set, it defaults to zero and effectively lies on top of your other divs to the side of the page. If you set a lower negative z-index on `#main-container` (and positioned it), this would also resolve your issue, although in my opinion, changing the negative z-index you have now to a positive one makes more sense.

Comment: Indeed. Never realized that negative z-index had that effect

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a positive z-index value. This should work.

[working version](http://jsfiddle.net/puTEe/1/)